# Cloudkit Dashboard - add test users

Tags: cloudkit

Goal: 
Create many fake users for development testing.

What I did:
Added 4 test users with different names on Cloudkit Dashboard as bellow:

[image]

Result:
The 4 created users show up on app with same name (always the name of the last one created).

Question: Is it possible to create multiple test users on  Cloudkit Dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

The way I create test users for CloudKit apps is by adding Apple IDs I own as admins of my app in App Store Connect: https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users

Then in the **CloudKit Dashboard**, I go to **Container Permissions** and give them access to the CloudKit container. I then sign them in on test devices using my app.

This might be more convoluted than you want, but if you don't manually manage users in your app, it might be the only way.

Comment: Is this still working for you? Trying to do the same but no one showing up in my Teams section in CloudKit Dashboard except for me.

Comment: Same for me. I created a new address only for testing purposes, and invited this address to join my team. I see the new account in the "Developer" part of the Users page on https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users. But when I try to add this new user on the container permission, I only see me (my main account). Can free developer account added to a team access a CloudKit dashboard? I really need this to test my app and see records in the private database (log the new user on the Simulator and a device to test sync is working, etc.).

Comment: Same issue for me. The user just won't appear on the permission section of the cloudkit container.